# CSS: How to prevent focus from breaking absolute position in overflow:hidden wrapper

Tags: html, css

I have a simple slider that also has an absolutely positioned element.  Everything is fine until focus is set to a link beyond the visible wrapper.  In this case, the absolute element is shifted to display the overflow hidden link.  It looks like the browser is shifting the wrapper (and the absolute element) instead of the internal div to bring the link into focus.  This can happen either programmatically or by using the Tab key.

I can't figure out how to keep the absolute element in the same place.  Any advice is appreciated!

```
<style>
    .thing {
        display:inline-block;
        width: 100px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
</style>

<div class="outer_wrapper" style="width: 300px; overflow: hidden; white-space: nowrap; background-color: #aaa; position: relative;">
    <div class="right" style="position: absolute; z-index: 1; right: 0; top: 0; background-color: #FF0000; height: 50px; width: 10px;">
    </div>

    <div id="strip" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="thing">
            <a href="#">something1</a>
        </div>
        <div class="thing">
            <a href="#">something2</a>
        </div>
        <div class="thing">
            <a href="#">something3</a>
        </div>
        <div class="thing">
            <a href="#" id="last">something4</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div onclick="document.getElementById('last').focus();">click me</div>
```

You can see the problem here: https://jsfiddle.net/s1ctnsut/

Just click the "click me" text and the absolutely positioned red element will shift to the left.  I want it to stay fixed to the right.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you cause scroll on the container its contents (*including the absolute positioned ones will also move accordingly*)

So make the `#strip` be 100% wide and `overflow:hidden`. This way the scroll will happen inside that and the red bar will not be affected

Adding

```
#strip{width:100%;overflow:hidden;}
```

will solve it ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gaby/s1ctnsut/1/))

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for the solution.  Just in case people are having similar issues, if I switch 'things' to float:left and strip to width: 10000px and overflow:hidden, I run into the same problem.